# Convert String to arry in PHP and print it

Tags: php

I have a sequence of numbers entered from the keyboard, I try to turn it into an array of all the numbers of that sequence and print the sum of those numbers. Eg:
Input: 12345
Print out: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
Please help me

Here is my code:

```
$input1 = "53687";
$arr = str_split($input1);
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
    $a = $arr[$i];
    $b = $a +1;
    echo $arr[$i] ."+". $arr[$b];
}
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have written so far.

Comment: "I want" isn't a question and doesn't describe a problem. You're supposed to show us what you've tried and explain exactly where you're stuck. See [ask]. We're not a free write-my-code service, even if (as in this case) the solution is pretty trivial. In fact there should be more than enough examples online of making an array and adding up the contents of an array already available, that you could do some simple research and make an attempt yourself - and that's the best way to learn anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `implode()` to create a string from an array with a delimiter between each.

You can use `array_sum()` to calculate the total of all the digits.

```
echo implode(' + ', $arr) . ' = ' . array_sum($arr);
```